# How to remove key from json response?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've got a collection `$tree` that is being converted to json with `Response::json()`. The key is being automatically set to the `id` of the first object. Is there a way to remove this, or restructure with:

```
'data': [
    { first object },
    { second object}
]
```

It is currently responding with:

```
{"1":{"id":"1","parent_id":null,"lft":"1","rgt":"8","depth":"0"...
```

When I want is:

```
{'data':[{"id":"1","parent_id":null,"lft":"1","rgt":"8","depth":"0"...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use: 
`Response::json(array( 'data' => array_values($yourDataArray) ) )`;

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
Response::json(array( 'data' => array_values($dataArray) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in PHP it would be easy, just use array_values() on the initial array so that it 'forgets' the array indexes (which by the way, is what 'RootName_X' is called in your case:

```
 $newvalue = array_values( (array)$value );
echo json_encode($newvalue);
```