# Getting incomplete data from database eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am facing very weird response from the eloquent query. It works fine if there are few set of data, but shows garbage if there is a huge set of data.

I haven't seen this type of error and I am very confused that what should I ask.

Here is my code:

```
$title = Input::get('title');
$movie = $this->where('name', 'like', $title.'%')->get(['id', 'poster', 'name', 'release_date']);
echo "<pre>";
dd($movie->toArray());
```

**Result I am getting (if there is a lot of data)**

```
array:2847 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "id" => 12
    "poster" => "http://ratersapp.com/posters/no-poster.jpg"
    "name" => "The Arrival of a Train"
    "release_date" => "1896-01-01"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "id" => 13
    "poster" => "http://ratersapp.com/posters/no-poster.jpg"
    "name" => "The Photographical Congress Arrives in Lyon"
    "release_date" => "1895-06-12"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
    "id" => 14
    "poster" => "http://ratersapp.com/posters/no-poster.jpg"
    "name" => "Tables Turned on the Gardener"
    "release_date" => "1970-01-01"
  ]
  .
  .
  .
  .
  623 => array:4 [
    "id" => 2206
    "poster" => "http://ratersapp.com/posters/no-poster.jpg"
    "name" => "The Outlaw Deputy"
    "release_date" => "1911-11-04"
  ]
  624 => array:4 [
    "id" => 2212
    "poster" => "http://ratersapp.com/posters/no-poster.jpg"
    "name" => "The Passions of an Egyptian Princess"
    "release_date" => "1970-01-01"
  ]
  625 => array:4 [ …4]
  626 => array:4 [ …4]
  627 => array:4 [ …4]
  628 => array:4 [ …4]
  629 => array:4 [ …4]
  630 => array:4 [ …4]
  631 => array:4 [ …4]
  632 => array:4 [ …4]
  633 => array:4 [ …4] // I don't know why I am getting this result set
```

**And I am getting proper result when there are only few set of data**

```
array:4 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "id" => 4538
    "poster" => "http://ratersapp.com/posters/no-poster.jpg"
    "name" => "Titanic: Echoes of Titanic"
    "release_date" => "1970-01-01"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "id" => 4540
    "poster" => "http://ratersapp.com/posters/no-poster.jpg"
    "name" => "Titanic: End of an Era"
    "release_date" => "1970-01-01"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
    "id" => 4545
    "poster" => "http://ratersapp.com/posters/no-poster.jpg"
    "name" => "Titanic: The Mystery & the Legacy"
    "release_date" => "1970-01-01"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [
    "id" => 4548
    "poster" => "http://ratersapp.com/posters/no-poster.jpg"
    "name" => "Titanic: Titanic Remembered"
    "release_date" => "1970-01-01"
  ]
]
```

**Can someone please help me to solve this.**

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **dumper** implementation that is used to **dump** data to your browser when you use **dd()** dumps only limited set of data in order to keep the response size reasonable. Items dumped after this limit is reached are not expanded anymore.

This limit is set to **2500** and all your records contain 4 fields, that's why you're getting only **625** rows expanded (**2500/4=625)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have tried with `print_r` and I got full data. But my problem is not solved actually I am returning this data in json formate by `return Response::json(['data' => $data])` but it adds indexing (0,1,2 ...) for each row in json data (only for large set of data, work fine for few set of data). So is there also any limit for `Response::json` method?

Comment: If you pass an array to Response::json, it calls json_encode internally, maybe it's some limitation of this method? I suggest you check the docs and discussions below on http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thank you jedrzej.kurylo, My problem has been solved by using `array_value`. `return Response::json(['data' => array_values($data)])`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257260/how-to-remove-key-from-json-response